# Some JPEGs from micro SD card munged, others OK

Tags: photos

Relevant contents of micro SD card:

437 files in *DCIM > Camera* directory

- 177 JPEGs can't be read (HEX dump begins with 0000 instead of FFD8)
- 138 are damaged (HEX dump includes a series of 0000 bytes)
- 118 photos are intact
- 3 videos can't be read
- 1 video is intact

548 files in *LOST.DIR* directory

---

Photos viewed from card in camera or PC yield same results, as do photos copied to hard drive.

Damages to photos include

- blank pixels, sometimes of a single color
- chunks of photo out of order
- chunks of photo missing colors

**Are damaged/illegible photos/videos hopelessly munged or can they be recovered?**

Here is a sample image that shows all of these problems, along with its thumbnail that I recovered with JPEGsnoop.

[image]